# re-import module-under-test to lose context

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, python-module

Many Python modules preserve an internal state without defining classes, e.g. `logging` maintains several loggers accessible via `getLogger()`.

**How do you test such a module?**
 Using the standard [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) tools, I would like the various tests inside a `TestCase` class to re-import my module-under-test so that each time it loses its context. Can this be done?

Comment: besides re-importing the module, which may be necessary in some instances, if the state you are resetting is nicely enclosed in one or a few attributes of the module, you can just use `mock.patch` to mock them out, and the mocks will be swapped out for the other tests.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
import unittest
import sys

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        try:
            del sys.modules['logging']
        except KeyError:
            pass
    def test_logging(self):
        import logging
        logging.foo=1
    def test_logging2(self):
        import logging
        print(logging.foo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.sys.argv.insert(1,'--verbose')
    unittest.main(argv = unittest.sys.argv)
```

`% test.py Test.test_logging` passes:

```
test_logging (__main__.Test) ... ok
```

but
`% test.py Test.test_logging2` does not:

```
test_logging2 (__main__.Test) ... ERROR
```

since the internal state of `logging` has been reset.

Answer (score 11):

This will reimport the module as new for you:

```
import sys
del sys.modules['my_module']
import my_module
```

Comment: i think you mean `del sys.modules['my_module']`