# Mock, import, and coverage

Tags: python, mocking, code-coverage

I am writing a small console wrapper so that we can some pretty colours on the console.  A cut down version of the module I use is here:

```
from sys import stderr
try:
    from fabulous.color import fg256
    clog = lambda x: stderr.write(
        str(fg256(63, u'\u26A0 ' + str(x).encode('utf-8') + '\n').as_utf8))
except ImportError:
     _green = '\033[1;32m'
     _default = '\033[1;m'
     clog = lambda x: stderr.write(_green +
                                   u'\u26A0 ' +
                                   str(x).encode('utf-8') +
                                   _default +
                                   '\n')
```

I can easily write some unit tests using `from mycolour improt clog` and the right version of `clog` will be picked up depending on the presence of fabulous or not. However, once the `clog` lambda is loaded, you cannot unload it.  Thus, any attempt to test (via py.test) both paths of the code fails on whichever is the second one.

How can I achieve 100% test coverage for this?

Here's the test script I have:

```
try:
    import builtins
except ImportError:
    import __builtin__ as builtins
import unittest
from mock import MagicMock
from mock import patch
from mock import call


class ColourFabulousTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    @patch('mycolours.stderr')
    def test_fabulous_clog(self, err):
        from mycolours import clog
        err.write = MagicMock()
        clog('ook')
        self.assertTrue(err.write.called)
        self.assertEqual([call('\x1b[38;5;63m\xe2\x9a\xa0 ook\n\x1b[39m')],
                         err.write.call_args_list)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass


class ColourANSITest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.realimport = builtins.__import__
        def myimport(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level=0):
            if name == 'fabulous.color':
                raise ImportError
            return self.realimport(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
        builtins.__import__ = myimport

    def test_ansi_clog(self):
        from mycolours import clog
        builtins.__import__ = self.realimport
        with patch('mycolours.stderr') as err:
            clog('ook')
            self.assertTrue(err.write.called)
            self.assertEqual([call(u'\x1b[1;32m\u26a0 ook\x1b[1;m\n')],
                             err.write.call_args_list)

    def tearDown(self):
        builtins.__import__ = self.realimport
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `tearDown()` methods:

```
try:
    del sys.modules['mycolours']
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7460363/3227133) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1668223/3227133) more general questions.